# In LINQ, how a DbSet, collection of entities of one table can point to another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
 public PlutoDBContext()
        : base("name=PlutoDBContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CourseSection> CourseSections { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tblUser> tblUsers { get; set; }
```

===================================================================

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbContext = new PlutoDBContext();
        //var obj = dbContext.GetCourses();
        //foreach (var item in obj)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
        //}
        var ent = from c in dbContext.Courses
                  where c.Level ==2 && c.Author.AuthorID ==1
                  select c;
        foreach (var item in ent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Price);
        }
```

======================================================================

In the above LINQ c is a variable pointing to the table "Course"(dBcontext.Courses). "c.Level" is fine as "Level" is the column inside "Course" table.
But how can we use c.Author.AuthorId, "Author" is a different table and "AuthorId" is its column name,
and "c" is the collection of entities inside "Course" table.

I mean "c" should be able to access the properties of "Course" class only. How it is pointing to "Author" class and accessing its properties(c.Author.AuthorId).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visit [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx) to understand how EF manages one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships between entities.

for your scenario, I imagined that the relation between `Course` and `Author` is `one-to-many`, I mean that every course can have only one Author but An author can have several courses. so, for having this relation your model must be like below:

```
public class Course
{
   //Rest of your properties goes here

   [ForeignKey(nameof(Author))]
   public int AuthorId {get; set;}

   public virtual Author Author {get; set;}
}

public class Author 
{
   //Rest of your properties goes here

   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}
```

> How it is pointing to the "Author" class and accessing its properties(c.Author.AuthorId)?

With the above models, you will have a one-to-many relation between these two tables. so in your `Course` LINQ query, you will have access to `Author`.

```
from c in dbContext.Courses
              where c.Level ==2 && c.Author.AuthorID ==1
              select c;
```

good luck.

Comment: Got the concept.